# Dynamically Change Gridview SqlDataSource to Stored Procedure with Parameter from Code Behind

Tags: sql, asp.net

I have a gridview with following sqldatasource code:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TSOstring %>" SelectCommand="TSOList" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
```

I am using a textbox and button to search the value in the gridview. I am trying to control this from the code behind with the following code in the search_button click event.

```
            SqlDataSource1.SelectCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure; 
            SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "[dbo].[TSOSearchByDie]";     
            SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("@DieNo", TypeCode.String, txt_die.Text.ToString());
```

What I want to do is change the sqldatasource1 to a different stored procedure with a parameter called "@DieNo" in it . Pass the textbox value to the parameter and return the result. The problem i have is that it always give me the error "Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Procedure or function 'TSOSearchByDie' expects parameter '@DieNo', which was not supplied".

Any Thoughts?

Thanks!!

Problem solved. I don't need the @ sign in the code!!!